# Highlighting a graph with non-trivial vertex definitions

Tags: graphs-and-networks

When defining a graph whose vertices are sets e.g. the Kneser graph, how does *Mathematica* interpret the vertices?

I am having trouble highlighting vertices when I define vertices with sets, but for some reason highlighting edges creates no problem:

```
HighlightGraph[Graph[{{1, 2} <-> {3, 4}}], {{1, 2} <-> {3, 4}}]
```

This creates an edge with the edge highlighted, as expected.  However

```
HighlightGraph[Graph[{{1, 2} <-> {3, 4}}], {1,2}]
```

does not highlight the vertex corresponding to `{1,2}`.

I originally had a colleague help write a program to construct the general Kneser graph.  However, when using `FindIndependentVertexSet`, it lists the correct vertices (sets), but when using `HighlightGraph`, it doesn't highlight anything; using `FindHamiltonianCycle`, I can highlight the cycle though.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a bug.
You may use this alternative syntax:

```
g = Graph[{{1, 2} <-> {3, 4}}]; 
SetProperty[{g, {{1, 2}}}, GraphHighlight -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Unfortunately, this method, which works for me a few hours ago (on my local Mathematica 10.2 install), fails now. It return `$Failed`.